# How to conduct a flash loan on PancakeSwap?

Tags: pancakeswap, flash-loans, flashbots

Apparently it's possible to take a flash loan on PancakeSwap, being that it's a fork of Uniswap. However, I haven't found any examples anywhere of a flash loan on PancakeSwap, nor do the docs mention it anywhere.

What's the simplest example of a contract taking a flash loan from PancakeSwap?

The flash loan would:

1. Borrow a certain amount of some token (say CAKE) from PancakeSwap
2. Pay back the required amount of the token

Answer (score 3):

PancakeSwap is a fork of Uniswap V2, which allows flashswaps. An example of flashswap using Uniswap V2 can be found here: https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/examples/ExampleFlashSwap.sol

it is invoked by calling the swap function of the Uniswap V2 pair you wish to take the loan from, which will call a callback function in your contract. It originates from this line in the UniswapV2Pair.sol contract(source: https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol):

```
if (data.length > 0) IUniswapV2Callee(to).uniswapV2Call(msg.sender, amount0Out, amount1Out, data);
```

In pancake everything is the same, except instead the name of the callback which becomes `pancakeCall` (instead of `uniswapV2Call`)

```
if (data.length > 0) IPancakeCallee(to).pancakeCall(msg.sender, amount0Out, amount1Out, data);
```

All you need to do is change the the function signature in your FlashLoan Receiver method from this:

```
function uniswapV2Call(address sender, uint amount0, uint amount1, bytes calldata data) external override { ... }
```

to this

```
function pancakeCall(address sender, uint amount0, uint amount1, bytes calldata data) external override { ... }
```

Edit: link to the pancakeswap pool contract here: https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-core/blob/master/contracts/PancakePair.sol

you will need to specify the address of the pool you wish to take the loan from

Comment: Edited the terminology (it's a flash swap, not a flash loan) + it's a callback function (where the flashswapped token is used)