# Flashloan + flashbot

Tags: uniswap, flash-loans, flashbots, mev, arbitrage

Can i use both **flashloan** and **MEV builder** in one transaction? Means borrowing from flashloan, then building my transaction in MEV builder (to prevent sandwich attack )?
If it is possible, can anyone recommend me good flashloan and MEV builder contract address?

Comment: What do you want to do?
You want to flashloan and then use that money across transactions in a bundle?
Flash loan has to be paid within same transaction. The contract you borrow from will callback the paying contract and want payment then. Balancer is free and has good documentation.

Comment: what i want to do is borrow X amount of coin then swap for Y amount. But in order to prevent sandwiching i wrap the swap transaction with MEV builders. I think the purpose of MEv builders are to give some privacy to gas fee bid. right?

Comment: does Balancer have API access like using infura rather than theGraph?

Comment: You need to use a contract that will do it atomically, see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"What I want to do is borrow X amount of coin then swap for Y amount. But in order to prevent sandwiching I wrap the swap transaction with MEV builders."

You can do this. The loan needs to be initiated and repayed by a smart contract which has a function that conforms to the called back function from the loaning contract.

For Balancer with a contract written in Solidity that could look like this:

```
contract FlashLoanRecipient is IFlashLoanRecipient {
    IVault private constant vault = "0xBA12222222228d8Ba445958a75a0704d566BF2C8";

    function makeFlashLoan(
        IERC20[] memory tokens,
        uint256[] memory amounts,
        bytes memory userData
    ) external {
      vault.flashLoan(this, tokens, amounts, userData);
    }

    function receiveFlashLoan(
        IERC20[] memory tokens,
        uint256[] memory amounts,
        uint256[] memory feeAmounts,
        bytes memory userData
    ) external override {
        require(msg.sender == vault);
        ...
    }
}
```

You would call the makeFlashLoan function, passing an array of tokens and amounts, vault would send the contract the tokens, and call the receiveFlashLoan function.
Your logic would go there, where at the end you would transfer the amount borrowed, back to the vault.

https://docs.balancer.fi/reference/contracts/flash-loans.html

Gave examples of some other flash loans in response to a similar, though by no means duplicate, question: [Finding IUniswapV2Callee in UniswapV2 clones for flashloans](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/153189/finding-iuniswapv2callee-in-uniswapv2-clones-for-flashloans/153492#153492)

For front running protection, you can use the eth_sendPrivateTransaction method with a flashbots endpoint:

```py
eth_sendPrivateTransaction = {
    'jsonrpc': '2.0',   
    'id': str or int,   
    'method': 'eth_sendPrivateTransaction',
    'params': [{
    'tx': [str],
    'maxBlockNumber': str,     
    'preferences': {       
    'fast': bool,       
    'privacy': {            
      'hints': [             
        'contract_address',       # exclude       
        'function_selector',      # these        
        'calldata',               # to only share
        'logs',                   # the hash
        'hash'         
      ],         
      'builders': [      
        'default',           
        'flashbots'         
      ],       
      }     
    }
  }]
}
```

Build the json object:

```py
{ 'id': 0, 'params': [{ 'tx': signed_private, 'maxBlockNumber': hex(TARGET_BLOCK + 10), 'preferences': { 'fast': False, 'privacy': {  'hints': [  'hash'  ],  'builders': [  'default',  'flashbots'  ], } } }] }
```

Sign it with a key created only for signing flashbots messages:

```py
def sign_flash(_tx_body: str) -> str:
  message = messages.encode_defunct(text=w3.keccak(text=_tx_body).hex()) 
  signature = f'{Account.from_key(FLA).address}:{w3.eth.account.sign_message(message, FLA).signature.hex()}'
  return signature
```

Then send directly to the flashbots endpoint:

```py
def send_flash(_request: dict) -> bytes:
  request = dumps(_request)
  headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Flashbots-Signature': sign_flash(request) }
  return post('https://relay-goerli.flashbots.net', data=request, headers=headers).content
```

https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-auction/searchers/advanced/rpc-endpoint/

Comment: Ok... give me some time... let me see it in detail.....

Comment: You can test on goerli, balancer and flashbots are there.
Good luck on your journey.

Comment: hello bro. things are now clearer more for me. i can successfully access flashbot thanks to u. But i see that balancer don't have RPC-API access.Right? any other flashloaners with RPC API?

Comment: Hm I don't know any flash loan that works like that, they need to be able to roll it back if you don't pay.

Comment: ok..So. i must deploy smart. Can u give code snippet or a link that contain source code written in solidarity to do this?. Sorry for saying this but , i only know c++ that's why i ask this.

Comment: I don't have any examples written in solidity. Though they should be the easiest to find with a look up. In the v2 answer, I linked a working bentobox flashloan, written in vyper, so easy to follow. But if you will have to learn the language anyway and you are comfortable with cpp, you might be better off just learning something like huff, from the start. It will give you a much better chance of designing competitive bots. Either way if you just take time to get comfortable with a language and the individual core mechanics, how they fit together will just make sense.

Comment: Ok bro. Thanks very much 

Comment: Hello maka. I need help here pls https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/156307/getamountin-equivalent-of-uniswapv3-or-how-to-calculate-it/156310#156310

Comment: Hey, can give time in a couple of hours

Comment: ok bro...thanks for ur response

Comment: I think short answer is you need to swap optimistically and use the numbers in the callback just like docs say, because there isn't a gas efficient way to do the calculation in your contract on chain. The long answer is that with an example and then to walk through the calculations for output amount with Liquidty and sqrtPrice in a single price range, before applying that across multiple. I did start an attempt at the answer but haven't had time to finish. Still don't think you can start with amountOut and get exact amountIn like v2, notice uni and sushi front ends removed that for v3.

Comment: ok thanks a lot brother ..