# getAmountIn equivalent of uniswapV3 or how to calculate it?

Tags: uniswap, pancakeswap, uniswapv3, uniswapv2, sushiswap

I was exploring uniswap V3 router, quoter and factory contracts, but it doesn't have `getAmountIn` function to calculate the minimum amount I must input to get the desired amount. On some thread, I found this code to do `getAmountOut` equivalent but not for getAmountIn.

```
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/libraries/FixedPoint96.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/libraries/FullMath.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Factory.sol';

  function calculatePriceFromLiquidity(
    address token0,
    address token1,
    uint24 fee,
    address factory
  ) public view returns (uint256) {
    IUniswapV3Pool pool = IUniswapV3Pool(IUniswapV3Factory(factory).getPool(token0, token1, fee));
    (uint160 sqrtPriceX96, , , , , , ) = pool.slot0();

    uint256 amount0 = FullMath.mulDiv(pool.liquidity(), FixedPoint96.Q96, sqrtPriceX96);

    uint256 amount1 = FullMath.mulDiv(pool.liquidity(), sqrtPriceX96, FixedPoint96.Q96);

    return (amount1 * 10**ERC20(token0).decimals()) / amount0;
  }
```

So can u tell me how to calculate `getAmountIn` please ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/Souq-G-Commerce/souq-etf/blob/main/contracts/exchange/UniV3ExchangeSwap.sol) contract that I built for this exact purpose

In your code, you can do something similar, and use the Uniswap [quoter](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/interfaces/IQuoter.sol) contract to get the quote you desire. This is how to call the function:

`quoter.quoteExactInputSingle(_tokenIn, _tokenOut, _fee, _amountIn, 0);`

Comment: the calling way u mentioned will revert in solidity code(on chain) due to quoteExactInputSingle is not view function and it changes state. The only way to call quoteExactInputSingle is off chain using callstatic. But i want to get amountIn on chain. Is thier a way to do this?