# How to buy on one exchange and sell on another with a flash loan

Tags: solidity, flash-loans

So, I’m trying to buy a coin on one exchange and sell the coin on another using the flash loan. In this example, specifically PancakeSwap and Uniswap V3. I actually copied a template, specifically “Appendix - Flash Borrower Example smart contract” from the Equalizer documentation and added more code and tweaked a few things.

But when I try to compile the code, it says there is a parser error. And when I try to resolve it, it says there is another one! This goes on and on and it’s ANNOYING ME TO DEATH!

There may be an incredible amount of problems with this code for all I know, and if you could help me resolve all the mistakes, that would be so appreciated it isn’t even funny. I’m praying to God for an answer.

I used Liquity USD as an example coin to trade, and I’m not sure if I could really trade that from PancakeSwap to Uniswap, as it is listed on one exchange but not the other.

On with the code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.18;


interface IERC20 {
   function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}


interface IERC3156FlashBorrower {
   /**
    * @dev Receive a flash loan.
    * @param initiator The initiator of the loan.
    * @param token The loan currency.
    * @param amount The amount of tokens lent.
    * @param fee The additional amount of tokens to repay.
    * @param data Arbitrary data structure, intended to contain user-defined parameters.
    * @return The keccak256 hash of "ERC3156FlashBorrower.onFlashLoan"
    */
   function onFlashLoan(
       address initiator,
       address token,
       uint256 amount,
       uint256 fee,
       bytes calldata data
   ) external returns (bytes32);
}


/*
*  FlashBorrowerExample is a simple smart contract that enables
*  to borrow and returns a flash loan.
*/
contract FlashBorrowerExample is IERC3156FlashBorrower {
   uint256 MAX_INT = 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff;


   // @dev ERC-3156 Flash loan callback
   function onFlashLoan(
       address initiator,
       address token,
       uint256 amount,
       uint256 fee,
       bytes calldata data
   ) external override returns (bytes32) {
      
       // Set the allowance to payback the flash loan
       IPancakeSwapV2Router02 private constant cakeRouter = IPancakeSwapV2Router02(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);
address private constant LUSD = 0x5f98805A4E8be255a32880FDeC7F6728C6568bA0;


IUniswapRouter private constant uniswapRouter = IUniswapRouter(0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564);
address private constant BNB = 0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52;


constructor() {
 IERC20(LUSD).safeApprove(address(uniswapRouter), type(uint256).max);
      
       // Build your trading business logic here
       // e.g., sell on uniswapv2
       // e.g., buy on uniswapv3
function _tradeOnCake(uint256 amountIn, uint256 amountOutMin, uint256 deadline) private {
   sushiRouter.convertByPath{value: msg.value}
    
   cakeRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
       amountIn,
       amountOutMin,
       _getPathForPancakeSwap(),
       recipient,
       deadline
   );
}


function _getPathForPancakeSwap() private pure returns (address[] memory) {
   address[] memory path = new address[](2);
   path[0] = BNB;
   path[1] = LUSD;
  
   return path;
}


function _tradeOnUniswap(uint256 amountIn, uint256 amountOutMin, uint256 deadline) private {
   address tokenIn = LUSD;
   address tokenOut = BNB;
   uint24 fee = 3000;
   address recipient = msg.sender;
   uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96 = 0;
  
   ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams(
       tokenIn,
       tokenOut,
       fee,
       recipient,
       deadline,
       amountIn,
       amountOutMin,
       sqrtPriceLimitX96
   );
  
   uniswapRouter.exactInputSingle(params);
   uniswapRouter.refundBNB();
  
   // refund leftover BNB to user
   (bool success,) = msg.sender.call{ value: address(this).balance }("");
   require(success, "refund failed");
}


// meant to be called as view function
function multiSwapPreview() external payable returns(uint256) {
   uint256 bnbBalanceUserBeforeTrade = IERC20(BNB).balanceOf(msg.sender);
   uint256 deadline = block.timestamp + 300;
  
   uint256 amountOutMinSushiSwap = 1;
   uint256 amountOutMinPancakeSwap = 1;
  
   _tradeOnPancakeSwap(msg.value,
 amountOutMinSushiSwap, deadline);
   _tradeOnUniswap(IERC20(LUSD).balanceOf(address(this)), amountOutMinUniswap, deadline);
  
   uint256 bnbBalanceUserAfterTrade = IERC20(BNB).balanceOf(msg.sender);
   return bnbBalanceUserAfterTrade - daiBalanceUserBeforeTrade;
}




function multiSwap(uint256 deadline, uint256 amountOutMinUniswap) external payable {
   uint256 amountOutMinPancakeSwap = 1;


   _tradeOnCake(msg.value,
 amountOutMinPancakeSwap, deadline);
   _tradeOnUniswap(IERC20(INJ).balanceOf(address(this)), amountOutMinUniswap, deadline);
}


       // Return success to the lender, he will transfer get the funds back if allowance is set accordingly
       return keccak256('ERC3156FlashBorrower.onFlashLoan');
   }
}


 // important to receive BNB
 receive() payable external {}
}
```

Comment: It's recommended to never deploy code you don't fully understand to the blockchain. But can you provide the exact error message you get, the function you are trying to call when you encounter the error, and the input parameters?

Comment: What Nero said is most true when it comes to this, although the contract looks ok. The docs for each loan provider have minimal viable examples and you should really attempt to recreate them, while getting comfortable with the smart contract language you want to use. As well as be able to debug a swap without a flash loan.
Some minimal examples here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/153189/finding-iuniswapv2callee-in-uniswapv2-clones-for-flashloans/153492#153492 / https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/153776/flashloan-flashbot/153785#153785

Comment: ```ParserError: Expected ';' but got 'private'
--> equalizer arbitrage.sol:48:31:
|
48 | IPancakeSwapV2Router02 private constant cakeRouter = IPancakeSwapV2Router02(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);
| ^^^^^^^```

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what the first word to type is when creating a flash loan all by myself, so I figured I would follow people's leads when it comes to creating flash loans, and I also figured their code was proven unlike mine would be, so I'd be less confident about my code than other people's codes. For all I know, you might say my mindset should be the opposite of this so say what must be said, please.

Comment: onFlashLoan the called back function doesn't seem to do anything accept set some constants that I think should be set outside of the function. Seems like missing closing braces all over. It doesn't seem like a direct copy of a working example, is it meant to be?

Comment: I need clarification about the “called back function”, setting something “outside of the function”, and “missing closing braces”.

Comment: Also, I did copy examples, but tweaked one in an intent to trade on PancakeSwap instead of SushiSwap. That same example also uses Bancor, but I removed that as Bancor cannot be used in the United States where I’m from.